# Resample over midnight 00h - compute min, max mean - custom label

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm new to Pandas... and I couldn't find a way to solve this simple problem.
How can I

- take data between [22h to 06h of the next day] both included,
- compute them to count-min-max-mean,
- resample the result in a Dataframe by day with custom label like `night #1 2017-10-12 22h-06h` `night #2 2017-10-13 22h-06h` etc ?

Data comes from a csv file that comes from a temperature probe at a rate of 1 per minute, it is sorted, but the start and end are not always clean and neither does the recording rate. Sometimes it starts at 21:13:00 with a rate of 5 per minute. So I try to work *only* with date and not count a number of rows.

You can find below a small setup which mimics the problem (I use increasing numbers instead of °C values to check the average after compute):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range('01/11/2017 21:00:00', periods=10000, freq='min')
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(10000)), columns=['T1'], index=index)
df.index.name='Datetime'
#df
```

I can extract data from 22h to 06h with between_time

```
df_light = df.between_time('22:00','06:00')
#print(df_light.to_string())  #Useful to see the whole list
df_light.head()

                        T1
Datetime    
2017-01-11 22:00:00     60
2017-01-11 22:01:00     61
2017-01-11 22:02:00     62
2017-01-11 22:03:00     63
2017-01-11 22:04:00     64
```

And use resample().agg()

```
result = df_light.resample('D', base=0).agg(['count','min','max','mean']).round(2)
result.head()

           T1
           count    min     max     mean
Datetime                
2017-01-11  120     60      179     119.50
2017-01-12  481     180     1619    659.25
2017-01-13  481     1620    3059    2099.25
2017-01-14  481     3060    4499    3539.25
2017-01-15  481     4500    5939    4979.25
```

### first problem

resample calculates all the data *in* the day, i.e [00h01..06h and 22h..23h59] whereas I would like it to calculate from the end of the day until the morning of the next day, i.e [22h..06h of the next day].
In addition I couldn't find a way to make *both* inclusive.

I searched with `base` argument and `closed : {‘right’, ‘left’}` but I didn't find anything very convincing.

### second problem

I try to make custom label with increasing number to see how many nights there is, but i couldn't find a way to make a growing up number after night (#1, #2, #3 etc)

```
result.index = result.index.strftime('night %Y/%m/%d 22h-06h')
result.head()

                            T1
                            count   min     max     mean
night 2017/01/11 22h-06h    120     60      179     119.50
night 2017/01/12 22h-06h    481     180     1619    659.25
night 2017/01/13 22h-06h    481     1620    3059    2099.25
night 2017/01/14 22h-06h    481     3060    4499    3539.25
night 2017/01/15 22h-06h    481     4500    5939    4979.25
```

..if you think you can help me with this two problems..you are Welcome ! and many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution of the first problem:

Match the base to the beginning of the time interval (22:00), as for interval, every second one contains valuable aggregates, others are NaNs, hence using `dropna()`

```
result = (
    df_light
    .resample('12H', base=22)
    .agg(['count','min','max','mean'])
    .dropna()
    .round(2)
)
result.head()

                       T1                        
                    count     min     max    mean
Datetime                                         
2017-01-11 22:00:00   481    60.0   540.0   300.0
2017-01-12 22:00:00   481  1500.0  1980.0  1740.0
2017-01-13 22:00:00   481  2940.0  3420.0  3180.0
2017-01-14 22:00:00   481  4380.0  4860.0  4620.0
2017-01-15 22:00:00   481  5820.0  6300.0  6060.0
```

Solution of the second problem (slightly more complicated):

```
s1 = pd.Series(result.index.strftime('night #{} %Y/%m/%d 22h-06h'))
s2 = pd.Series(range(len(s1))).map(str)
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
new_index = df.apply(lambda x: x[0].format(x[1]), axis=1)

result.index = new_index
result.head()

                               T1                        
                            count     min     max    mean
night #0 2017/01/11 22h-06h   481    60.0   540.0   300.0
night #1 2017/01/12 22h-06h   481  1500.0  1980.0  1740.0
night #2 2017/01/13 22h-06h   481  2940.0  3420.0  3180.0
night #3 2017/01/14 22h-06h   481  4380.0  4860.0  4620.0
night #4 2017/01/15 22h-06h   481  5820.0  6300.0  6060.0
```

You can play around with the formatting of the new index, say use `range(1, len(s1) + 1)` for proper counting.

Comment: Thank you @Revaz, you just made a happy one on earth! :)